# spring integration sftp:inbound-channel-adapter delete-remote-files=false

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

We are using the spring integration sftp:inbound-channel-adapter to transfer data from a remote host. We would like to keep the files on the remote host. Thus we tried with the 
delete-remote-files=false option.

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter 
    id="sftpInboundChannelAdapter"
    channel="filesToParse"  
    session-factory="..."
    remote-directory="..." 
    filename-pattern="..." 
    local-directory="..." 
    temporary-file-suffix=".tmp" 
    delete-remote-files="false" 
    auto-create-local-directory="true" local-filter="localFileFilter"
>
```

Unfortunately these files are then processed multiple times. Is there a way of keeping the remote files and not processing them multiple times?

EDIT: this is because a subsequent process deletes the file on the local side.

```
    <bean id="localFileFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptAllFileListFilter"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that the `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` (which is in fact the default), will only prevent duplicates for the current execution; it keeps its state in memory.

To avoid duplicates across executions, you should use a [FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-inbound) configured with an appropriate metadata store.

Note that the `PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore` only persists its state to disk on an normal application context shutdown (close), so the most robust solution is Redis, or MongoDB (or your own implementation of `ConcurrentMetadataStore`).

You can also call `flush()` on the `PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore` from time-to-time (or within the flow).

Answer (score 0):

I changed the filter: it now only retrieves them once.

```
<bean id="localFileFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptOnceFileListFilter"/>
```